# How to remove shadow from JavaFX tabs?

Tags: java, javafx

I have tabs in JavaFX and I want to set a style to remove the shadows:

[image]

If you look at the left side of foo, you can see shadows.

This is my current style:

```
.tab {
    -fx-background-color: #393939;
    -fx-border-color: #282828;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
    -fx-padding: 1 8;
}
```

I've tried to look into the documentation, but could not find a way to remove shadows: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tabpane

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To find the default stylesheet, search for the file `jfxrt.jar` on your computer, open it in an archiver like WinRAR and open `com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian.css`. With this knowledge, you can easily see what could be there that causes the issue.

`caspian.css` is also available online, here is the a link to the [JavaFX 2.2 version](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/raw-file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css).

Now, add this style:

```
.tab-pane .headers-region {
    -fx-effect: null;
}
```

It removes the default style and the shadows are gone.

Comment: for JavaFX9 it's now in modena.css in a module file:  jdk-9.0.1\jmods\javafx.controls.jmod  \classes\com\sun\javafx\scene\control\skin\modena\